# Subsets of words inheriting genders from an (implicit) set

Tags: grammar, gender

This [new question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8796/worter-mit-selber-bedeutung-aber-unterschiedlichen-artikeln) has given me an idea.

---

The numbers, seen as nouns, are feminine (*die Eins, die Null,* usw.). This can be thought of as if they were "inheriting" the gender of their collective, *die Zahl*

> die (Zahl) Eins, …

(one understandable exception to the rule being *π,  das Pi*).

That doesn't happen for each object. For instance, the following "deduction" is false

> **der** Buchstabe *demzufolge ist* **der** (Buchstabe) A  ← (falsch!)

for the correct gender for letters is neutral. But something makes me think that this is rather an exception to the rule with the numbers above.

> **Example:**
>
> - Ich habe *eine* Krakauer und *ein* Paulaner gekauft.  Dannach habe ich auch *einen* Berliner gegessen.

The genders come from *die Krakauer-Wurst*, *Paulaner ist ein Bier* (das) and from *der Berliner-Pfannkuchen*, but *Wurst, Bier* and *Pfannkuchen* are tacit)

**Question:** Is there a rule that generalizes these examples? That is, a rule that allows us to apply the same gender of a tacit noun to its particularizations.

Comment: Das Schriftzeichen A, Das Symbol A. Und Pi ist für mich erstmal auch keine Zahl, sondern eine Konstante; und letztlich auch wieder nur ein Symbol. Und fragst du die Griechen ist es wiederum ein Buchstabe, bzw. Schriftzeichen oder Symbol. ;)

Comment: Btw. Ich musste gerade mal nachschlagen, was "Hund" mit "Meute" zutun hat. Ich kenne es nur im übertragenen Sinne einer großen Menschenmenge. Aber wenn schon - ohne es nachgeschaut zu haben, bin ich mir sicher, dass das Wort "Meute" jünger ist als das Wort "Hund".

Comment: @Em1 Ja, aber es gibt eine (fast) kanonische Zuordnung für *A*. 90% würde sagen, es sei ein Buchstabe.

Comment: Du fragst nach einer Regel, die es nicht gibt und nicht geben kann: Es gibt Regeln für die Genera mehrerer abstrakter Objekte: Buchstaben sind Neutrum, ganze Zahlen sind Femininum. (π ist übrigens ein Buchstabe und keine Zahl. Mathematiker verwenden den Buchstaben π lediglich als Symbol für eine Zahl.) Aber die Bezeichnungen dieser Mengen abstrakter Objekte haben damit gar nichts zu tun. Es gibt verschiedene Bezeichnungen mit verschiedenen Genera. Somit ist eine solche Regel unmöglich.

Comment: Die Mehrzahl (Meute) ist etwas anderes als ein Oberbegriff. Die Mehrzahl von Paulaner ist ja nicht Bier. Außerdem sind bei Paulaner und Krakauer die Begriffe Kurzformen, aber eben für Paulaner-Bier und nicht für Bier schlechthin. Allgemeiner wäre für Hund womöglich Rudeltier (s), Landräuber (m), Säugetier (s) aber Verallgemeinerungen lassen sich meist in viele Richtungen bilden.

Comment: @Em1: Pi ist sowohl eine Zahl, als auch ein Buchstabe und eine Konstante. 4 ist im Kontext der Jahreszeiten in unseren Breiten auch eine Konstante, aber kein Buchstabe. Aber c in E = mc² ist auch Buchstabe und Konstante.

Comment: Note that 80 % of Germans will have no idea that people from Berlin call what they call ‘Berliner’ ‘Pfannkuchen’, so that argument is invalid there. (Also, it’s one and only *correct* name is, of course, *Krapfen* ;))

Answer (score 6):

The way the question is asked right now leaves only one answer: yes. There are many groups in which the gender is not conserved because there is no such rule.

> der Mensch: die Frau, das Kind, der Mann
>
> das Tier: der Löwe, die Hornisse,..
>
> der Baum: die Eiche, die Ulme, die Birke,...
>
> das chemische Element: der Phosphor, das Blei,...

And there is no reason why such a rule would exist. In many areas the words came first and then came the categories. Just think of *das Möbelstück*. *Tisch* and *Stuhl* are certainly older than that.

I have tried to think of a way to modify the question such that it would only ask for a very specific set of categories but I wasn't able to grasp it. However, I think another example that you would call exception are the colors.

> die Farbe: das Rot, das Grün,...

Comment: Ja, ok. Ich muss die Frage ändern (wenn überhaupt noch Sinn macht). Vll. beziehe mich auf Dinge, deren Geschlecht schwer zu eraten ist, wüsste aber noch nicht, wie ich das erklären soll. (Bitte nicht *Nutella* als Gegenbeispiel geben `:)` )

Comment: Außerdem ist es so, dass Elemente verschiedenen Kategorien mit, natürlich, verschiedenem Geschlecht zugeordnet werden können, wie der Streit um Pi zeigt, welches natürlich sowohl eine Zahl, als auch ein Buchstabe ist, so wie ja auch Vier sowohl eine Zahl, als auch ein Wort ist oder ein Delphin ein Säugetier und ein Raubtier.