# Wörter mit selber Bedeutung, aber unterschiedlichen Artikeln

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, article

Mir ist heute beim Spazierengehen aufgefallen, dass die Wörter

> die Geldbörse, das Portemonnaie und der Geldbeutel

die gleiche Bedeutung, **aber** unterschiedliche Artikel haben – was ich irgendwie erstaunlich finde.
Gibt es einen Fachbegriff dafür, bzw. kennt ihr weitere solche Wörter?

Comment: Possibly related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8482/nouns-losing-the-gender-of-the-collective-substantive-describing-them/8484#8484

Comment: Willkommen bei GLU! Anderseits kenne ich keine Sprache, in der es eine Genusbeschränkung für Synonyme gibt.

Comment: Da das grammatikalische Geschlecht von Wörtern, die keinen Bezug zu irgendeinem biologischem Geschlecht aufweisen, gewissermaßen Zufall ist, besteht eigentlich immer, wenn zwei solche Wörter die gleiche Bedeutung haben, eine große Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass sich ihr grammatikalisches Geschlecht unterscheidet. Insofern finde ich das „Phänomen” nicht bemerkenswert genug, um ihm einen eigenen Namen zu verleihen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das grammatische Geschlecht hat absolut nichts mit dem Bezeichneten zu tun. Nichts. Bei neuen Wörtern spielt teils gleiche Lautung (der Blog), teils der Originalartikel (der Latte) und teils tatsächlich ein deutsches Synonym (die Latte) eine Rolle.
Im Großen und Ganzen aber ist das nicht der Fall und das Geschlecht hängt von Wortbildung und Etymologie ab. Daher gibt es auch unzählige Beispiele.

> Das Auto, der Wagen, die Karre
>
> der Blick, die Sicht, das Panorama
>
> die Frau, das Weib
>
> …

Comment: In dem empfehlenswerten Buch des Linguisten Guy Deutscher: Through the Languagae Glass mit dem Untertitel: Why the world looks different in different languages gibt es ein nettes Kapitel "Sex and Syntax". Dort stellt Deutscher die These auf, dass das grammatische Geschlecht eines Wortes Auswirkungen auf die dem Gegenstand zugeschriebenen Eigenschaften hat, die je nach der verwendeten Sprache (und damit dem grammatikalischen Geschlecht) männlich oder  weiblich ausfallen können.

Answer (score 2):

Man sollte dabei beachten, dass sich der Artikel immer auf den letzten Teil des Wortes bezieht. *Die Börse*, *der Beutel* – lediglich *Portemonnaie* ist ein Wort, welches nicht aus zusammengesetzten Nomen besteht. Das kann man im Grunde mit jedem Nomen, welches Synonyme hat, machen.

> Der Wall, die Mauer, das Bollwerk

Bei *Laptop* und *Notebook* wirds heikel, denn da sind diverse Artikel in Benutzung.

Comment: Was hat die Frage der Zusammensetzung damit zu tun?

Comment: der artikel ist immer auf das zweite eigentliche "nomen" bezogen. deswegen

Comment: Das ist mir schon klar. Mir ist nicht klar, was es mit dem Problem zu tun haben soll. "Der Laden, das Geschäft" sind 2 andere Hauptwörter für eine gleiche Sache die keine Zusammensetzungen sind. Das Phänomen der Zusammensetzung verhält sich völlig neutral zur Frage, ob Substantive unterschiedlichen Geschlechts das gleiche Ding bezeichnen können. Es lenkt nur vom Thema ab.

Comment: das thema ist doch genau passend, k.a. was dein problem ist. Gleiche bedeutung anderer artikel. beispiel ist  : geldbörse und portemonnaie. der user fragt ob wir weitere beispiele kennen oder obs nen begriff dafür gibt, für ihn war es scheinbar eine seltenheit. emanuel hat dann direkt gesagt, dass es unzählige beispiele gibt und ach ist mir zu doof....

Comment: Außerdem steht die Behauptung im Raum, Portemonaie wäre kein zusammengesetztes Wort. Gewagt, gewagt. :) Porter=tragen monaie=Moneten.

Comment: zusammengesetzten Nomen.